# Partial residuals plot

Tags: r, regression, generalized-additive-model

I am trying to understand how the `gam` package in R generates the partial residuals plots, so I tried to create one from scratch to compare to the one generated by `plot.gam()`, but they don't match. I wanted to try as simple an example as possible, so I am only using one variable, $lstat$, as a predictor of $medv$, in the Boston housing prices dataset.

```
library(MASS)
library(gam)
lm.fit.Boston.1 <- lm(medv ~ lstat, data = Boston)
summary(lm.fit.Boston.1)
## Coefficients:
## Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
## (Intercept) 34.55384    0.56263   61.41   <2e-16 ***
## lstat       -0.95005    0.03873  -24.53   <2e-16 ***
```

Then plot the partial residuals:

```
plot.gam(lm.fit.Boston.1, se=TRUE)
grid()
```

[image: GAM plot]

If I am understanding Introduction to Statistical Learning, p. 285 (footnote at bottom), correctly, the partial residual plot is the best-fit line of $lstat$ as a predictor of the partial residuals, in this case $r_i=y_i-\beta_0$.

```
beta_0 <- coef(lm.fit.Boston.1)[1]
y <- Boston$medv
r <- y - beta_0
lm.residuals <- lm(r ~ Boston$lstat)
plot(Boston$lstat, lm.residuals$fitted.values)
grid()
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong, why aren't the plots identical? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You don't compute the partial residuals correctly.

As the footnote in Section 7.7.1 *GAMs for Regression Problems* of ISLR explains:

> Partial residuals for $X_3$ have the form $r_i = y_i - f_1(x_{i1}) - f_2(x_{i2})$.

To compute the partial residuals for $X_3$ we estimate $f_1$ and $f_2$ by fitting a (GAM) model for $Y$ on $X_1$ and $X_2$. We don't use $X_3$ in this "partial" model. In your example there is only one predictor, `lstat`. So the intercept `1` plays the role of $X_1$ and $X_2$ and `lstat` — the role of $X_3$.

*What you did wrong*: You used the full model `medv ~ 1 + lstat` to compute partial residuals for `lstat`. 
*What you should do instead*: Use the partial model `medv ~ 1`.

[ISLR] G. James, D. Witten, T. Hastie, and R. Tibshirani. *An Introduction to Statistical Learning with Applications in R*. Springer, 2nd edition, 2021. Available [online](https://www.statlearning.com).

Here are the partial residuals plots. To make it easier to compare plots, I use the same x:y ratio.

```r
lm.full    <- lm(medv ~ 1 + lstat)
lm.partial <- lm(medv ~ 1)

# This is the plot we want to reproduce by hand
make_gam_plot(lm.full)
```

[image]

```r
# This is the wrong way to compute partial residuals for `lstat`
# as we use `lstat` in the model which produces the residuals
resid <- medv - coef(lm.full)["(Intercept)"]
lm.full.residuals <- lm(resid ~ lstat)

make_base_plot(lstat, fitted(lm.full.residuals))
```

[image]

```r
# This is the right way to compute partial residuals for `lstat`
resid <- medv - coef(lm.partial)["(Intercept)"]
lm.partial.residuals <- lm(resid ~ lstat)

make_base_plot(lstat, fitted(lm.partial.residuals))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

R code to reproduce the figures:

```r
attach(MASS::Boston)

xlim <- c(0, 40)
rlim <- c(-30, 20)

make_gam_plot <- function(model) {
  gam::plot.Gam(
    model,
    se = TRUE,
    xlim = xlim,
    ylim = rlim
  )
  grid()
}

make_base_plot <- function(x, y) {
  plot(x, y,
    xlim = xlim,
    ylim = rlim
  )
  grid()
}

lm.full <- lm(medv ~ 1 + lstat)
lm.partial <- lm(medv ~ 1)

make_gam_plot(
  lm.full
)

resid <- medv - coef(lm.full)["(Intercept)"]
lm.full.residuals <- lm(resid ~ lstat)

make_base_plot(
  lstat, fitted(lm.full.residuals)
)

resid <- medv - coef(lm.partial)["(Intercept)"]
lm.partial.residuals <- lm(resid ~ lstat)

make_base_plot(
  lstat, fitted(lm.partial.residuals)
)
```